# update table in foreach loop

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

Have a problem. Just cant find problem. I have 2 tables first one kampe: hold1, hold2, hold1goal,hold2goal and another hold: hold, fgoal, agol. Im trying to get all hold1goal and hold2goal to fgoal and agoal in the hold table. Im quite new to sql.

```
<?php
include "config.php";

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM kampe') as $row){

        $fgoal = $row['hold1goal'];
        $agoal = $row['hold2goal'];
        $hold = $row['hold1'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE hold SET fgoal = :fgoal, agoal = :agoal WHERE hold = :hold");                                  
        $stmt->bindParam(':fgoal', $fgoal); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':agoal', $agoal); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':hold', $hold);   


        $stmt->execute(); 


        /*   print $agoal . "\n";

        $fgoal = $row['hold2goal'];
        $agoal = $row['hold1goal'];
        $hold = $row['hold2'];

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE hold SET fgoal = :fgoal, agoal = :agoal WHERE hold = :hold");                                  
        $stmt->bindParam(':fgoal', $fgoal); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':agoal', $agoal); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':hold', $hold);   



        $stmt->execute(); */
}
?>
```

this is the result. only 'Odensevej' changes. Thought the foreach loop would change all.

KAMPE

```
INSERT INTO `kampe` (`kampID`, `hold1`, `hold2`, `hold1goal`, `hold2goal`) VALUES
(1, 'marksvej', 'holdet', 0, 0),
(2, 'tervej', 'dfdf', 0, 0),
(3, 'Odensevej', 'holdet2', 2, 1),
(4, 'hest', 'hestener', 0, 0),
(5, 'holdet', 'tervej', 0, 0),
(6, 'dfdf', 'marksvej', 2, 6),
(7, 'Odensevej', 'hest', 0, 0),
(8, 'hestener', 'holdet2', 3, 1),
(9, 'dfdf', 'holdet', 0, 0),
(10, 'tervej', 'marksvej', 0, 0),
(11, 'hestener', 'Odensevej', 2, 1),
(12, 'holdet2', 'hest', 0, 0),
(13, 'Odensevej', 'holdet', 0, 0),
(14, 'dfdf', 'holdet2', 0, 0),
(15, 'hest', 'tervej', 2, 3),
(16, 'hestener', 'marksvej', 0, 0),
(17, 'holdet2', 'holdet', 0, 0),
(18, 'Odensevej', 'marksvej', 0, 0),
(19, 'hest', 'dfdf', 0, 0),
(20, 'tervej', 'hestener', 0, 0),
(21, 'hest', 'holdet', 0, 0),
(22, 'marksvej', 'holdet2', 0, 0),
(23, 'tervej', 'Odensevej', 0, 0),
(24, 'dfdf', 'hestener', 0, 0),
(25, 'holdet', 'hestener', 0, 0),
(26, 'hest', 'marksvej', 0, 0),
(27, 'tervej', 'holdet2', 0, 0),
(28, 'Odensevej', 'dfdf', 3, 2);
```

HOLD

```
INSERT INTO `hold` (`id`, `hold`, `leder`, `telefon`, `email`, `fgoal`, `agoal`, `p`) VALUES
(6, 'holdet', 'kim anov', '345345', 'kimanov@gmail.com', 0, 0, 0),
(20, 'marksvej', 'svend dellepude', '345345', 'kimanov@gmail.com', 0, 0, 1),
(61, 'tervej', 'Kim Test', '34343434', 'kim@anov.dk', 0, 0, 1),
(64, 'dfdf', 'dfdf', 'dfdf', 'kim@anov.dk', 0, 0, 0),
(67, 'Odensevej', 'Brian Anov', '34343434', 'brian@anov.dk', 3, 2, 2),
(69, 'holdet2', 'asda asdasd', '4234234', 'dsfsf@sdfsd.com', 0, 0, 0),
(70, 'hest', 'kim a', '323423', 'adas@asda.dk', 0, 0, 0),
(71, 'hestener', 'asdasd asdasd', '3423423423', 'safsdfasdasd.com', 0, 0, 2);
```

Comment: What is the question? :?

Comment: **HOW** is this not working for you?

Comment: it only inserts data from last row in kampe to hold. dont understand why it dont loop and insert all values to the different hold.

Comment: use `$stmt->errorInfo();` to find out if there any database errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question about why your query result's loop is failing you, but... there is no reason why you should be looping in PHP to do this. One query will do both the SELECT and the UPDATE:

```
update hold h
left join kampe k on
    k.hold1 = h.hold
set
    fgoal = k.hold1goal,
    agoal = k.hold2goal
```

Adding a PHP loop into the mix dramatically increases your overhead for what is a relatively straightforward `UPDATE` query in your DB.

Comment: worked almost. one game did'nt register. used $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE hold h LEFT JOIN kampe k ON k.hold1 = h.hold SET fgoal = k.hold1goal, agoal = k.hold2goal");                                     $stmt->execute();

Comment: You may want to check that that game appears in the similar SELECT statement: `SELECT * FROM hold h LEFT JOIN kampe k on k.hold1=h.hold` If it's not in there, or the kampe values are NULL then it means that either `kampe` doesn't have a value for that `hold` record.